# CSS: opacity causes slight background color variation

Tags: html, css, opacity, background-color

I have set a specific background color for the body. I then want to use another div with the same background color but with opacity: .95 as a mask for content animating from the bottom of the page. This results in the masking div appearing to be a slightly different color. Is there any way around this?

See a screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHdI7.png) and the sample CSS below. I'm on Chrome 20 on Lion.

```
body
{
    background: #3f3c45;  
}

#bottommask
{
    background: #3f3c45;
    opacity: .95;
}
```

UPDATE: Please check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dtailed/c6V8V/) demonstrating the issue

---

**UPDATED SOLUTION**: It seems that at least in Chrome, using -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; on the mask div solves the issue.

Comment: Thats what is supposed to happen with opacity. Do you understand how opacity works?

Comment: ummm, what did you expect it to do? A lighter shade of that color... is a "slightly" different looking color

Comment: I would have thought that if I change just the opacity and have the same color underneath that the the difference would not show.

I know very well how opacity works and what I was expecting is exactly what Photoshop does, but I guess this is not how browsers handle it.

Is there any other way of achieving this effect, if not with opacity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It it a matter of computing the effect of the 5% color gain from below.

Three ways:

- calculating, or
- trial/error with Firebug color picker, or
- make a screenshot and sample the transparent color, then apply the sampled color to the non alpha background.

For the tattoo site, I've changed to a slightly different color, in order to accounting for the color shift of the opacity.

```
body {
    background: #8d918f;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Eric, but I've tried rgba and the result is the same.

I think you've misunderstood me, I'm talking about pure color on pure color.

Here's a fiddle demonstrating the issue: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/dtailed/c6V8V/)

Comment: @dtailed Let me know if this is what you need.  A `div` with a slight transparent content, but keeping the same color as below?

Comment: That's it. It doesn't even have content, it just needs to be slightly transparent but still have the same color as below.

Comment: @dtailed I don't understand why do you need it to be slightly transparent then.  I think you just need to get rid of the `opacity`

Comment: I've done something similar for http://www.thefamilybusinesstattoo.com/ (scroll down after the page loads to see the mask) but because of the lighter shade of grey the difference is less noticeable, but still present.

Comment: @dtailed ha I made this http://compef.com and I have the same issue but since yours is a color it is possible let me play with the tattoo site.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I guess in the end I'll manually have to pick colours if there's no other way.